# How to set page title of panel page

Tags: 7, panels

I have a panel page that includes several views. I want to use the title field of one of the views as the page title. So far, I have not been able to figure out how to do this.

I have installed [Panel Variant Page Title](https://www.drupal.org/project/panel_variant_page_title) module. However, I don't seem to have access to the field I want to use. The closes substitution available is `%arg:title`.

If I use this substitution, the page title is set to the whole URL.

Any ideas about how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

Go to the Panel Configuration page into the *Content* section. Now choose in the dropdown field *"Title type"* the value *"From pane"*.

Now select a pane with the view and click on the configuration link of this pane and choose *"pane title"*.

Your Panel shows now the title of your selected pane.

Comment: For now this option seems not work

Comment: i guess its for drupal 7 only.

Comment: Yes, the solution is for drupal 7 @Eez